# Axis2 Code Generator Wizard - Eclipse Indigo installation

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-axis

I'm trying to install "Axis2 Code Generator Wizard" for Eclipse Indigo following the installation instruction but, when I start eclipse, I cant't find the wizard to create a new project like this:

http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/eclipse/wsdl2java-plugin.html#Installation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved installing 1.7 version instead:

[axis2.eclipse.service.plugin-1.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar](https://builds.apache.org/job/Axis2/lastStableBuild/org.apache.axis2%24axis2.eclipse.service.plugin/artifact/org.apache.axis2/axis2.eclipse.service.plugin/1.7.0-SNAPSHOT/axis2.eclipse.service.plugin-1.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar) and [axis2.eclipse.codegen.plugin-1.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar](https://builds.apache.org/job/Axis2/lastStableBuild/org.apache.axis2%24axis2.eclipse.codegen.plugin/artifact/org.apache.axis2/axis2.eclipse.codegen.plugin/1.7.0-SNAPSHOT/axis2.eclipse.codegen.plugin-1.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar)